# Are DS/DSi flash cards compatible with the 3DS and 3DS XL?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-ds, emulation

I love to play emulated SNES games in my DSi XL, using an Acekard 2i. I'm about to buy a 3DS XL and I need to know if it will suffice all my emulation needs. Thanks.

Comment: I used to own an *Action Replay* card for cheating; it only worked on my DSLite, but not on my DSi or 3DS. Because of that, I'd say the probability of a DS flashcard working on a 3DS is *really* low.

Comment: Close voters closing as off-topic: This seems to be on-topic as per the ff: [meta] post, [What's the official stance on console emulation?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuperCard DSTWO still works with the 3DS with the latest update (6.3.0-12), as long as you keep the card's firmware updated.

Keep in mind that if your 3DS already has the latest update, you might not be able to update the card itself. You'll need a 3DS with a lower firmware version or a DS.

Comment: DSTWO have good SNES emulators and have a satisfatory FPS count?

Comment: Haven't had much experience with SNES emulation. [This review](http://gbatemp.net/threads/supercard-dstwo-review.232281/#post-3254876) by GBATemp.net gives a pretty deep rundown of the pros and cons.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this site](http://gbatemp.net/threads/whats-the-best-ds-flashcart-for-3ds.314058/) Acekard 2i works with the 3ds.

Comment: That thread is from 2011.  It's a couple years out of date; last I checked, the 3DS had an update that more or less disabled every single flashcard out there, except for a rare few.